# Regex: how to find 3 or more matches in a row NOT ONLY one by one

Tags: python, regex

I try to find rows in my file where '1/1' or '0/0' occur 3 or more times. I use regex in Python. I test my regex with https://regex101.com/.

Here is the part of my input file:

```
0   chr1  1152 NaN   G   A   1355.64     NaN   1/1   0/1   0/1  0/1   1/1   0/1   0/1   0/1   0/1   1/1   0/1   0/1
4   chr1  1331 NaN   A   C   4171.07     NaN   0/0   0/1   0/1  0/1   0/0   0/1   0/1   0/1   0/1   0/0   0/1   0/1
5   chr1  1349 NaN   T   C  11194.50     NaN   0/1   0/1   0/1  0/1   1/1   0/1   0/1   0/1   0/1   1/1   0/1   0/1
6   chr1  1401 NaN   T   G  10825.80     NaN   0/1   0/1   0/1  0/1   1/1   0/1   0/1   0/1   0/1   1/1   0/1   0/1
8   chr1  4045 NaN   G   T   1917.92     NaN   1/1   1/1   1/1  1/1   1/1   1/1   0/1   1/1   0/1   1/1   0/1   1/1
```

I wrote a regex to find the beginning of the line:

```
r"^\d\s{3}(chr\d)?\s{2}\d+\s+\D+\d+\.\d+\s+\w+"
```

but I have a problem with the next part. I've tried:

```
r"^\d\s{3}(chr\d)?\s{2}\d+\s+\D+\d+\.\d+\s+\w+(\s{2,}1/1|\s{2,}0/0)"
```

but it finds just the first occurrence of '1/1' or '0/0'. When I try to use:

```
r"^\d\s{3}(chr\d)?\s{2}\d+\s+\D+\d+\.\d+\s+\w+((\s{2,}1/1){3,}|(\s{2,}0/0){3,})"
```

then there is just one match where '1/1' occurs three times or more but one by one:

```
8   chr1  4045 NaN   G   T   1917.92     NaN   1/1   1/1   1/1  1/1   1/1   1/1   0/1   1/1   0/1   1/1   0/1   1/1
```

Any ideas on how to find all rows with >= 3 '1/1' or '0/0'?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? [`^(?=(?:.*?(?:0\/0|1\/1)){3,}).*$`](https://regex101.com/r/jpiocv/1)

Comment: Should the row be matched if it contais 2 `0/0` AND 1 `1/1`?

Comment: @GurmanjotSingh The question states `'1/1' or '0/0' occur 3 or more times`

Comment: Another possibility. [`^.*(?:(?:(?:1\/1)|(?:0\/0)).*?){3,}.*`](https://regex101.com/r/JK8OLF/2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep the first capture group, you can use your first pattern, followed by matching 3 times either 0/0 or 1/1

```
^\d\s{3}(chr\d)\s{2}\d+\s+\D+\d+\.\d+\s+\w+(?:(?:\s{2,}\d/\d)*?\s{2,}([10])/\2\b){3}
```

The second part of the pattern:

```
(?:(?:\s{2,}\d/\d)*\s{2,}([10])/\2){3}
```

- `(?:` Non capture group to repeat as a whole

  - `(?:` Non capture

    - `\s{2,}\d/\d` Match 2 or more whitespace chars
  - `)*?` Close group and optionally repeat non greedy
  - `\s{2,}` Match 2 or more whitespace chara
  - `([10])/\2\b` Capture either 0 or 1 in group 2, and match `/` followed by a backreference to group 2 to match up the digits for `0/0` and `1/` followed by a word boundary to prevent a partial match
- `){3}` Close group and repeat 3 times

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/11qXVh/1)

If you also want to match the rest of the line, you can append `.*` to the pattern.

Comment: Nice, I might have taken the wrong take on the question. Honestly thought OP was looking for the same seqence a minimum of 3 times. But this also makes sense!

Comment: @Thefourthbird, thanks a lot for your solution. To be sure, in this part `([10])/\2\b` there is matching only '0/0' or '1/1' when you use '\b'?

Comment: @emor it matches `0/0` or `1/1` and the  word boundary is there to prevent matching `1/19` for example

Comment: @Thefourthbird, could you write me a suggestion on how to change the second part of your regex to find rows with >=3 `0/0` AND >=3 `1/1`? I'm trying to modify it but without satisfying results..

Comment: @emor So you mean that `0/0` should be there 3 times AND `1/1` should be there 3 times?

Comment: @Thefourthbird exactly

Comment: @emor Try it like this `^\d\s{3}(chr\d) {2}\d+ +\D+\d+\.\d+ +\w+(?=(?:(?:\s+[01]/[01])*?\s+1/1){3})(?:(?:(?:\s+[01]/[01])*?\s+0/0){3})(?:\s+[01]/[01])*$` https://regex101.com/r/dkftVI/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird, it works great, but could you explain to me the last part: `(?:\s+[01]/[01])`? Your regex is working without it too so I'm curious why we should add it.

Comment: @emor Yes but you want to match the whole line right? So if you don't add matching the rest of the line, then you get this https://regex101.com/r/sjrzyM/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird, ok, I guess that when you use `.*$` instead of `(?:\s+[01]/[01])` then it matches the whole line too. Is there any difference in the potential unwanted matches or missing matches between them?

Comment: @Thefourthbird, ok, I see it now - it matches just strings like `0/0` or `1/1` or `0/1`. Thanks, you help me think :D

Comment: @emor That is what I mean yes. Well, the `.*` matches any character, and `(?:\s+[01]/[01])*` matches the already existing pattern

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could use a positive lookahead:

```
^\d\s{3}(chr\d){2}\d+ +\D+\d+\.\d+\s+\w+(?=.*(([10])/\3)(?:.*\2){2})(?:\s+[10]/[10]){12}$
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/fXyhlz/1)

The added part `(?=.*(([10])/\3)(?:.*\2){2})(?:\s+[10]/[10]){12}$` means:

- `(?=` - Open a positive lookahead;

  - `.*` - Match 0+ (Greedy) characters other than newline;
  - `(([10])/\3)` - A 2st capture group to catch either a 1 or 0 that repeats itself after the forward slash;
  - `(?:.*\2){2}` - Open a non-capture group to match 0+ characters upto the pattern captured in the 2nd capture group and match two times;
  - `)` - Close positive lookahead;
- `(?:\s+[10]/[10]){12}` - A 2nd non-capture group to match 1+ whitespace characters and the pattern of 1s and 0s with the forward slash as delimiter. Match this group twelve times;
- `$` - End-line anchor.

Comment: Ah, you match the allowed data 12 times, that's also a good solution. Perhaps as a suggestion, you also use the data format in the assertion https://regex101.com/r/D72s7J/1

Comment: True @Thefourthbird, but it may compromise readability =). Either way I would like to know from OP if the assumption of matching the same pattern three times was the right one to begin with.

Comment: @JvdV, thank you for your solution.  I'm not sure if I understand correctly your regex. Why in `(?:.*\2){2}` there is matching two times? I need to find all rows where '1/1' occurs >=3 or '0/0' >=3.

Comment: It does that (check the link), but we can stop the positive lookahead if we have found three occurences @emor

Answer (score 0):

This will work :

If 0/0 appears more than 3 times for any line :

```
(.*(?:0\/0\b).*){3}
```

If 1/1 appears more than 3 times for any line :

```
(.*(?:1\/1\b).*){3}
```

If 0/0 appears 3 times or 1/1 appears 3 times

```
(.*(?:1\/1\b).*){3}|(.*(?:0\/0\b).*){3}
```

If any of 0/0 1/1 appears 3 times

```
(.*(?:1\/1\b).*){3}|(.*(?:0\/0\b).*){3}|(.*((?:0\/0\b)|(?:1\/1)).*){3}
```

0/0 :
[image]

1/1 :
[image]

If 0/0 appears 3 times or 1/1 appears 3 times
[image]

If any of 0/0 1/1 appears 3 times
[image: If any of 0/0 1/1 appears 3 times]

Comment: While this might work, you are not taking the initial pattern of the OP into account so this might also match just `1/1/1/1/1/1` Did you note the number of steps for the pattern to complete? See https://regex101.com/r/vx9Lhv/1 And even more worrying when there is no match, see https://regex101.com/r/0lWuDf/1

Comment: no it wont match 1/1/1/1/1/1

Comment: I think it does https://regex101.com/r/yIELAg/1

Comment: right.. this is taking 1/1/1/1, but will work with input, emor is providing